# Laravel Voyager - Redirect to a different page after saving user preferences

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am using Laravel Voyager to develop an application. Users are added using admin account which has all the rights.

If a normal user whose role doesn't have access to browse users logs in to the application and tries to save his details after editing profile, gets a 403 forbidden error.

Is there any way in Voyager, through which I can set the redirect URL after user saves the data?

Comment: I want to restrict user to edit and view only his details on the app. He shouldn't be able to view other users.

Comment: is there any way to override /users route in laravel voyager?